# Deploying Front End of Website to Azure

Tags: web-services, azure, gruntjs, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my web application and web service to Azure. I am somewhat new to web development and even newer to web app deployment.

When I test deployment on my local machine, there are 2 steps:

1) Publish web service from within VS. Copy generated folder to server's inetpub/wwwroot/ folder, convert to application from IIS manager. - **I refer to this as the back end.**

2) Host and run the web app. Run "grunt build" to generate a "dist" folder, copy dist folder into inetpub/wwwroot, create new site pointing to this folder in iis manager. - **I refer to this as the front end.**

I seem to have gotten step 1 done correctly in Azure: http://nxgnopencast.azurewebsites.net/ - published it to Azure from within Visual Studio. 
My issue is step 2. What is the equivalent of grunt building and using iis manager to convert to website for Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying all of the content on your IIS website into the wwwroot folder on your Azure web app. This can be done easily via FTP or drag and drop on the SCM site: http://nxgnopencast.scm.azurewebsites.net/

On the SCM site go to Debug console > CMD and then use the folder structure to go to D:\home\site\wwwroot and drag and drop all of your content there.

[image]

For more deployment techniques see:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/